# pandas plt.legend issue. error says that 'legend only accepts two non-keyword arguments'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I use the below statement, extracting cell content as legend name (I have 3 set of values to plot on y-axis, thus need 3 legend parameters)

plt.legend(df.iat[0, 0], df.iat[0, 1], df.iat[0, 2])

the compiled error says that 'legend only accepts two non-keyword arguments'
I print out the df.iat[0, 0], df.iat[0, 0], df.iat[0, 0], all these 3 are the cell content I expect.
Anyone know how I can fix it?

Comment: Maybe you mean `plt.legend([df.iat[0, 0], df.iat[0, 1], df.iat[0, 2]])`, combining the labels into a list (supposing that you want these values as labels).  Could you create a minimal reproducible example?  Without it, it's very hard to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the values in a list:

plt.legend([df.iat[0, 0], df.iat[0, 1], df.iat[0, 2]])